# "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte" when querying string in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm querying to see if a particular URL exists in my table:

```
query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE LINK = %s)'
c.execute(query, [link])
result = c.fetchall()[0][0]
```

If I set link equal to "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-mideast-iran-tanker/iran-threatens-british-shipping-in-retaliation-for-tanker-seizure-idUSKCN1U00S5", it works fine. But when I specifically try:

```
query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE LINK = %s)'
c.execute(query, ["
https://www.reuters.com/article/brief-katanga-mining-receives-confirmati/brief-katanga-mining-receives-confirmation-from-kamoto-copper-co-that-armed-forces-of-drc-are-in-area-around-operations-of-kcc-idUSFWN24502R"])
```

I get:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 1: invalid start byte

This happened for another long URL. But the column type is `mediumtext`, and it's the same type I'm using for much longer strings.

Comment: Looks like your codec is choking on the byte order mark, but I’m not really sure what to do about it..

Comment: `SELECT LEFT(HEX(link), 10) ...` would show the FF and make it obvious if there is a BOM.

Comment: @RickJames the problem is I can't actually get these strings into the database so I can't select them

Comment: Then see if you can get the HEX from python.

Comment: @RickJames hex for the first 10 characters is `68:74:74:70:73:3a:2f:2f:77:77`

Comment: Hmmm... No [_BOM_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#bom_byte_order_mark) there.

Comment: Do you have this at the beginning of your code?  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` ?

Comment: See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=codec%20decode%20byte

Comment: I got the same error and fixed it by renaming a column (column that was a subquery, therefore it had a strange default name)